# Best linq-able way to see is there matching object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following line which checks is there matching object

```
var foo = someVar.Single(x => x.ID.ToString().Equals(txtIDField.Text));
```

question is

what is best practice or which code snippet do you use to check is foo contains null and if not use above statement to select single value?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. `foo` is the variable that you want to initialize with the linq query. So how can that be null before you execute the query? If `foo` was null before it makes still no sense since you are not using it in the query itself. Maybe you meant `someVar` instead.

Comment: @panjo please restate your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var foo = someVar.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString().Equals(txtIDField.Text));
```

> Returns a single, specific element of a sequence, or a default value
>   if that element is not found.

[SingleOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx)

Then check foo is not null

```
if (foo != null)
{
    // do something with foo
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx), it returns true / false if there is any item in a collection that matches a certain condition:

```
bool haveItem = someVar.Any(x => x.ID.ToString().Equals(txtIDField.Text))
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) instead, [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) throws an exception if the record doesn't exist e.g.

```
var item = someVar.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString().Equals(txtIDField.Text));
if (item != null)
{
    // item exists!
}
```

If you are asking from a general point of view, here are my rules:

- `Single()`/`First()` - Returning a single item which I know exists.
- `SingleOrDefault()`/`FirstOrDefault()` - Returning a single item which *may* exist.
- `Where()` - Returning multiple items which *may* exist.
- `Any()`/`Contains()` - Checking if an item exists

Deciding which one to use really comes down to what you are doing. For example, if you are just looking to check if the record exists but have no intention of using it I would recommend using `Any()` or `Contains()` simply because they are quicker. However, if you need to actually do something with the record after finding it then the other retrievial queries are more optimial i.e. `FirstOrDefault()`/`SingleOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options here depending on what you want you can use  any of these

IEnumerable.First(),

IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(),

IEnumerable.Single,

IEnumerable.SingleorDefault,

Any.

**Usage**

`First()` will throw an exception if no element is found for the specified conditions

`FirstOrDefault`() will return default(T) or null in case of a reference type).

use `Single` when you expect only one record, will throw an exception if no element is found for the specified conditions

use `singleorDefault` when you expect single or default record, wont throw an exception

use `Any` if you only want to check (not select) if there is any record satisfying your conditions

Comment: You have more than two options...`Single`/`SingleOrDefault`/`Where`/`Any`/`Contains`/`Find` etc.

Comment: @James i was editing that :)